# Not able to get cookie from Node to React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

I created a simple login system where after certain user logs in the backend I set profile cookie with jwt token value

```
           res.cookie('profile',jwt_token,{
                secure : false,
                httpOnly : true
           });
```

In React frontend I am sending a get request to Node backend where I expect to get that jwt token

```
             const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:2000/users/test', {withCredentials:true});
```

This is my controller for getting a cookie

```
export const test = async (req,res) =>{
   try {
         const cookie = req.cookies.profile || "no cookie";
         res.json(cookie);
    } catch (error) {
         console.log(error.message);
         res.status(406).json({success:false});
    }
 };
```

When I try to get a cookie after logging in with Postman I get cookie value but when I try to get the cookie from React through axios i am getting 'no cookie'. I've also set app.use(cors()) in Node

Comment: are you using express server with node?

Comment: @danwebb Yes I am

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently a known Axios bug exists that can be solved like this. Just add this line of code and try again.

```
 axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
 const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:2000/users/test', {withCredentials:true});
```

Comment: Still nothing, in postman I get req.cookies.profile but when I send request to get it from React it is equal to { }

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the `cookie-parser` middleware http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html and then add it to your app:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

//...

app.use(cookieParser())
```

Comment: @t3_rry yes I have this installed

Comment: i know it's been almot two years but how did you solve this issue